# Find Record associated with a Max Date Value Golang Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

```
type History struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID           `bson:"_id"`
    ConfigId     string                       `bson:"configId"`
    IsClosed    bool                          `bson:"isClosed"`
    CreatedTime  time.Time                    `bson:"createdTime"`
    ValidityTime time.Time                    `bson:"validityTime"`
}
```

Here is my MongoDB data Struct

I want to achieve this

1. Find the record with the latest config time group by config Id
2. Later filter all the configs where IsClosed = true and ValidityTime less than the present time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. You must show your research, result, errors to get some help from the SO community

Answer (score 0):

For the second case you can use `$match` stage in aggregate:

```
{
  isClosed: true,
  validityTime: {$lt: ISODate()}
}
```

golang example aggregate:

```golang
histories := []*History{}

cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{
bson.D{
        {"$match",
            bson.D{
                {"isClosed", true},
                {"validityTime", bson.D{{"$lt", time.Date(2022, 10, 13, 6, 2, 38, 0, time.UTC)}}},
            },
        },
    },
})
if err != nil {
   return nil, err
}

if err := cursor.All(&history); err != nil {
   return nil, err
}
```

please more explain about:

> Find the record with the latest config time group by config Id